# Googlebot is accessing .aspx pages, it should access SEO-friendly URLs only

Tags: asp.net, seo, friendly-url, googlebot

Googlebot is accessing `.aspx` pages in my website e.g http://mysite.com/thepage.apx?id=32

I have  used Intellgencia URL module for SEO-friendly URLs and my website also has links that present friendly URLs (or extensionless URLs) e.g.: http://mysite.com/thepage/32.

However, googlebot is accessing original URLs (http://mysite.com/thepage.apx?id=32).

In the robot.txt file I have placed following code:

> disallow: *.aspx

My question is whether it will hide all pages with `.aspx` pages and friendly URLs (pointing to same `.aspx` pages) or hide pages just with `.aspx` extensions.

Summary:
googlebot is accessing same page with two urls:

1. With original path e.g somesite/thepage.aspx?id=xx
2. With friendly URL somesite/somepage/xx I want googlebot to access only friendly URLs. I am using asp.net 2.0 and friendly urls are mapped in `web.config` using intellgencia dll.

Code in web.config with Intellgencia module.

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="/category/(.+)" to="/categoryPage.aspx?Id=$1"/></rewrite>
</rewriter>
```

Comment: googlebot will access what you allow it to access. Are do any of your links include `?id=xx` and then redirect after the fact?

Comment: googlebot is accessing same page with two urls:1 with original path e.g http://somesite/thepage.aspx?id=xx 2: with friendly url http://somesite/somepage/xx I want googlebot to access only friendly URL.I am using asp.net 2.0 and friendly urls are mapped in web.config using intellgencia dll.

Answer (score 0):

I think your url mapping is wrong. Your aspx urls are supposed to be mapped too.

Comment: googlebot is accessing same page with two urls:1 with original path e.g somesite/thepage.aspx?id=xx 2: with friendly url somesite/somepage/xx I want googlebot to access only friendly URL.I am using asp.net 2.0 and friendly urls are mapped in web.config using intellgencia dll.

Comment: Its what Im saying, your original url must be blocked, redirecting for not found, redirecting for the mapped url, or something else. If a user get to "something.aspx?id=123", instead of "123/something" just redirect him for the proper url with permanently moved. If he access "something.aspx", send the user to not found, or a home. Google will learn it and will drop out the resource.

I just block all aspx resources with a regex rule, all .aspx files gives a not found error. Google learn it in one day.

Comment: do you mean I have to write another URL rewritting module in httpmodule.I have already used Intellgencia module for User friendly urls. see my questions , I have edited it with my web.config code.It works in my application but again i dont want googlebot to access url with original path.

Comment: please you give some example about "permanently moved" or regx you have done.

Comment: I mean your original URL must have some kind of treatment. Whatever the module for url friendly you use, check the url (page pre init?), and if the url is something.aspx do a smart redirect with:
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"; Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.domain.com"); Google will not index the old url and will drop the resourse. You can use your url friendly module to get where you want to, just map the original url to the mapped url.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are typos in your `Disallow` statement - it should read `Disallow: /*.aspx$` - see this aricle  http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449 on Google Webmaster tools and scroll down to the section on Pattern matching.

Comment: yres i have used same statement. disallow: /*.aspx$